# Percentage differences between rows with matching column values with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a pandas expression that will find the margin of victory in percentage terms between the two candidates by finding the candidate with the greater amount of votes, finding what percentage of the county votes they have and then subtracting the lesser of the two candidates' vote total percentage to find a margin of victory like this, all while kind of ignoring the third party candidate and go from this.

```
YEAR         STATE      County              CANDIDATE           VOTES
2016         Ohio       Medina County      Donald Trump         184211
2016         Ohio       Medina County      Hillary Clinton      398271
2016         Ohio       Medina County      Gary Johnson         12993
2016         Ohio       Cuyahoga County    Donald Trump         54810
2016         Ohio       Cuyahoga County    Hillary Clinton      32182
2016         Ohio       Cuyahoga County    Gary Johnson         2975
```

..to this

```
YEAR         STATE      County              CANDIDATE           VOTES       MARGIN OF VICTORY
2016         Ohio       Medina County      Donald Trump         184211      Hillary Clinton +35.1%
2016         Ohio       Medina County      Hillary Clinton      398271      Hillary Clinton +35.1%
2016         Ohio       Medina County      Gary Johnson         12993       Hillary Clinton +35.1%
2016         Ohio       Cuyahoga County    Donald Trump         54810       Doanld Trump +24.6%
2016         Ohio       Cuyahoga County    Hillary Clinton      32182       Donald Trump +24.6%
2016         Ohio       Cuyahoga County    Gary Johnson         2975        Doanld Trump +24.6%
```

Comment: How do you define margin of victory?

Comment: so you would take the candidate's votes for the county, divide them by the county's total votes overall, and then you would subtract the smaller of the two from the larger of the two

Comment: But there are three candidates. Could you show with numbers how you get 35.1?

Comment: yeah sure so hillary clinton got 65.4% of the total vote in the county, donald trump got 30.3% of the vote and gary johnson got 2.1% of the vote. 65.4 - 30.3 = 35.1

Comment: So, you subtract the second largest from the largest? But then you should get (398271-184211)/(184211+398271+12993)=35.9%.

Comment: essentially yes because we can assume that no third party candidate will come close to the amount of votes a democrat or republican would get in a county

Comment: You cannot write a number-crunching program without sticking to a precise formula.

Comment: my math was wrong.. you are correct. so the total amount of votes for the county is 595475, so you would take (398271/595475) - (184211/595475) * 100 and you get 35.9

Answer (score 0):

> Unsure on how you are intending to calculate the margins. The below is
> to outline the approach you can take not the correct answer

You would need to aggregate the data first at `YEAR STATE COUNTY` level

```
df_agg = df.groupby(by=['YEAR','STATE','COUNTY'])['VOTES'].sum().reset_index().rename_column({'VOTES':'AGG_VOTES'})
```

You can join back this df to the original `df` and use the `AGG_VOTES` column to generate the required statistics

```
df = pd.merge(df,df_agg,on=['YEAR','STATE','COUNTY'])
df['Candidate_Percentage'] = df['Votes'] * 100 / df['AGG_VOTES']
```

You can further aggregate your `df` to roll it up to get a consolidated `df` with the required margin victory

Comment: Your answer does not produce the margins.

Comment: Right , the answer does not provide the margins intended here , my idea was to outline the approach he can take , as I was unclear as well how 35.1 is calculated

Comment: see my comment above how i got the margins, thanks for the reply!

Comment: It is advised not to answer a question unless you fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very awkward solution, but it works. The function `do_county` processes one county at a time.

```
def do_county(data):
    return (data.set_index('CANDIDATE').sort_values('VOTES') \
            / data['VOTES'].sum())\ # Normalize
                .diff().tail(1) # Take the diff between top two

df.groupby(['County', 'STATE', 'YEAR']).apply(do_county)
#                                               VOTES
#County          STATE YEAR CANDIDATE                
#Cuyahoga County Ohio  2016 Donald Trump     0.251514
#Medina County   Ohio  2016 Hillary Clinton  0.359478
```

I am sure there is a better way to solve the problem.